# Графика в SWI Prolog. XPCE библиотека

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Доброго дня.
Я никак не могу найти нормальный источник информации о XPCE инструментарии для написания оконных приложений на Prolog.
Из толкового что нашел это на ютубе уроки по создании графики в Prolog на испанском.
Документация на оф.сайте SWI Prolog бедна на информацию.
Может кто-то знает нормальный учебник или сайт посвященный данному вопросу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Может кто-то знает нормальный учебник или сайт посвященный данному вопросу?

Вот нашёл тут кое-что: [logic programming for swi-prolog](http://www.pdfdrive.net/logic-programming-for-swi-prologs-home-e743360.html)

Вот ещё:               [coursenotes.pdf](http://www.swi-prolog.org/download/xpce/doc/coursenotes/coursenotes.pdf)

И последнее:          [xpce userguide swi-prolog](http://www.pdfdrive.net/xpce-userguide-swi-prolog-e6177815.html)

Думаю, больше ничего ценного нет.

Первая ссылка, на мой взгляд, самая лучшая ...